# IoC Container - Registering Instance Components

Tags: inversion-of-control, instance, autofac, ioc-container

My question is with regards to instance registration in an Autofac IOC container.
In some cases, you may want to pre-generate an instance of an object and add it to the container for use by registered components. You can do this using the RegisterInstance method:

```
var output = new StringWriter();
builder.RegisterInstance(output).As<TextWriter>();
```

What would be a typical scenario example of performing instance registration and why?

Comment: Additional question removed. When asking on Stack Overflow, please ask only one question per Question. Otherwise, you may get several answers, and *Answer C* is the best answer for your first question, but *Answer B* is the best answer for your second question; then, which answer should you pick as *the* answer? If you have additional questions, please ask them as separate Questions.

Answer (score 3):

A typical example would be when you need to map a type, but the destination type is a Singleton (either globally, or in a particular context).

Imagine, for example, that you wish to register [`Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding), which is an abstract class, to [`UTF8Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding). While `UTF8Encoding` has a public constructor, it might be more efficient to register [`Encoding.UTF8`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8), which is a Singleton.

That might look like this:

```
builder.RegisterInstance(Encoding.UTF8).As<Encoding>();
```

In this particular example, it's only a performance optimisation, but in other cases, the Singleton instance may be the only available instance, and you'd *have* to do this.

Comment: Many thanks Mark for the clarification. Much appreciated.